# How to select 1 record and the associated records?

Tags: sql

I work with a publishing database and we keep records of books. Books can have multiple authors. We maintain a table which holds records of the authorship of books. I need a SQL Query to select an author and then also select the other authors who worked with them on each of their books.

The Authorship table looks something like this:

```
+---------+--------+
| Author  | BookID |
+---------+--------+
|    1    |    1   |
|    2    |    1   |
|    1    |    2   |
|    2    |    2   |
|    3    |    2   |
|    4    |    2   |
|    5    |    3   |
|    5    |    4   |
+---------+--------+
```

So if I selected Author 1 I want to see the authors they worked with. The result would return me authors 2,3, and 4.

The idea here is that I can generate a report for an Author that shows who they have collaborated with in their publishing career.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT author
FROM AuthorsBooks 
WHERE bookid IN(SELECT bookid
                FROM AuthorsBooks
                WHERE author = 1);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89f1f/5)

This will give you:

```
| AUTHOR |
----------
|      1 |
|      2 |
|      3 |
|      4 |
```

**Or:** using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b1.author
FROM AuthorsBooks AS b1
INNER JOIN AuthorsBooks AS b2  ON b1.bookid = b2.bookid
WHERE b2.author = 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89f1f/12)

Answer (score 2):

```
select a1.Author
from Authorship a
join Authorship a1 on a.BookID=a1.BookID
where a.Author=1

If you want to exclude the current author:

select a1.Author
from Authorship a
join Authorship a1 on a.BookID=a1.BookID
where a.Author=1 and a1.Author!=1
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here is what you can do.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Author  
FROM Authorship 
WHERE BookID IN(  
            SELECT BookID   
            FROM Authorship  
            WHERE Author = 1  
           ) 
AND Author <> 1
```

> [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ae6e/11)

Comment: +1, thanks, note that, Is SQLFiddle, you didn't need to create the table schema and the sample data manually. You can create them automatically, click the **`Text To DDL`** button then copy the sample data from the question and paste them their then press the append to DDL button. This will make you quicker :) :)